# Background image - padding changes size of background (with display block)

Tags: html, css

When you change the padding(top, bottom), it also changes (add 10px) the height of the background. How can I fix this? Vertically, it seems to work well.

http://jsfiddle.net/VyYB7/3/

I have added padding to my text/content.

Comment: Is the element able to grow larger that 220x122?

Answer (score 0):

Try using *margin* instead (or in addition) of *padding*, like so:

```
margin: 10px 0;
```

---

## EDIT

To use both padding and margin (so that the text will be padded):

```
margin: 10px 10px;
padding: 0 10px;
```

Comment: But I have to padding my text/content.

Comment: So you use it with addition to padding, I edited my answer with the code.

Comment: It's still doesn't work for me. I need to center this text using padding.

Comment: If you want to center the text then: *margin:0px auto;*

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CSS [`background-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-origin) and [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-clip) properties. Set them to whatever works to get your background anchored in the right place (probably `content-box` for both).